# php arrays, their data comparing

Tags: php, sql, arrays, database

I have a login function, but there is one problem, before redirecting to the next page I have to check if `$user_data['isikukood']` is in `$tootaja_data` Maybe i'm doing something wrong? It doesen't works.

PhP

```
db_connect();
if (isset($_POST['login']) ) {
    $kasutajanimi = $_POST['kasutajanimi'];
    $password = $_POST['pass'];

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM isik WHERE nimi='$kasutajanimi'");
    $query_tootaja = mysql_query("SELECT isikukood FROM tootaja");

    $user_data = mysql_fetch_array($query);

    $count = 0;
    $tootaja_data = array();

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_tootaja))
    {
        $tootaja_data[$count] = $row;
        $count++;

    }

    if($user_data['parool'] == $password){

        foreach($tootaja_data as $value){
            if($user_data['isikukood'] == $value){
                header('Location: ../main.php/?view=tootaja');
            }else{
                header('Location: ../main.php/?view=klient');
            }        
        }
//        print_arr($tootaja_data);

    }else{
        header('Location: ../index.php');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In you code, you are comparing an  entire array to a string.

the `$value` in your loop looks most likely something like:

```
$value = array('isikukood ' => 'string');
```

What you should do is use [in_array](https://www.php.net/in_array)

```
if(in_array($user_data['isikukood'], $value)){ ...
```

or compare the exact elements:

```
if ($user_data['isikukood'] == $value['isikukood']){ ...
```

Comment: my `$tootaja_data` is looking like `Array
( [0] => Array([isikukood] => 39305267044)
  [1] => Array([isikukood] => 47563421869))` . If i'm using `in_array` or exact element compare in foreach cycle, then if condition is true only for last element. I don't know what to think, please help if yuo can